# Graphing a strobiloid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with household income for different countries and I would like to plot a strobiloid for the income distribution like the following: 
[image]

As can be observed and reported by Chauvel (2013) the vertical axes is simply the medianization of income (1=median income) and on the x-axis report the density of the normalized income. 
Therefore, after created the normalize and medianization variables, my current dataset is structured as follow:

```
dput(head(country2_1))
normalize = c(-1.1119191983758, -0.843550100237873, 
-1.17549225038817, 0.273065149036515, 0.273065149036515, 
-0.574581599038115))
medianization = c(0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4)
```

To replicate the strobiloid I tried to use the ggplot2 package:

```
ggplot(prova, aes(x=normalize, y=medianization)) + geom_violin(fill="lightblue")
```

with the following result: 
[image]

Is there a way to obtain a smoothed violin as if looks like a density? I cannot combine geom_violin and geom_density, but does exist an alternative? 
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Densities are univariate plots. You seem to have two variables here. Are you trying to make a density plot with summary data? I'm not sure there's a standard method for that. Do you have a reference to such a method? Maybe this is something you should ask at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: Exactly it seems to me as well, but I am just trying to replicate the strobiloids reported in the Chauvel (2013) paper, who is plotting the density of the normalized income on the x-axis and the medianization of the income on the y and this was the only way I figure out.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the normalized values on the y-axis? It seems strange to have the x-axis not be a discrete value, and to have the y-axis only have integer values

Comment: Is indeed what I tried at the beginning and with a much better graph representation,  but I was not sure the same interpretation of Chauvel still holds